# How to connect angular 7 with mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, server, angular7

I am creating a web application in Angular 7. So I want to connect angular 7 with mongodb for storing and retrieveing data from database.

anyone guide me to connect with mongodb using angular 7.

Comment: https://www.positronx.io/mean-stack-tutorial-angular-7-crud-bootstrap/  Angular is frontend applicaton so you need server side language to connect database or mongodb api to connect

Comment: to connect to MongoDB you should use server-side language as he said, you can choose nodejs ,python java spring, etc ..and make an API and conusme them in angular with HttpClient

Answer (score 1):

Maybe CouchDB is the better choice for your requirements (just a hint - there's a lack of information). It stores data as JSON and with Angular you can simply post to it via HttpClient.